# Download excel file through WinRT Webview component

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm loading a webpage inside my WinRT app using the webview component. The page loads fine, the JS and CSS seems to work fine too. The page has a button to export data from a datagrid to an excel file. The export feature works fine in any browser I tested. However, when I load the page inside webview and click the export link I got the following error:

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}
```

My question is: Should I enable something in the Webview component or in my app to enable the loaded webpages to activate download links?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem. I am facing a similar one.